# How can I create a crosstab/pivot table in pentaho data integration?

Tags: pivot-table, pentaho, kettle, crosstab

I would like to turn the first picture into the 2nd picture (and I'm too tired to embed the pics, sry) https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWU49.jpg (output: Excel)
I also dont want to use a java script.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use the Row Normaliser step, there are 2 different samples in the Samples directory of your PDI (\data-integration\samples\transformations).

There is also some examples on the Pentaho wiki, which you can access through the help button from within the step itself, in any case here is the link to it: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Row+Normaliser

There are also quite some examples of this step and other questions such as yours that have been answered here on stack and at other several PDI dev. blogs.

Comment: I think what he really needs is the Row Denormaliser: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Row+denormaliser